# Are there always singularities at the edge of a disk of convergence?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

Take a function that is analytic at 0 and consider its Maclaurin Series.  Here are some examples I'll refer to:

$$\frac{1}{1-x} =\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$$
$$\frac{1}{1+x^2} =\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nx^{2n}$$
$$\ln(1-x) =-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n}$$
$$\sqrt{1-x} =1-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2n-2)!}{2^{2n-1}n!(n-1)!}x^n$$

Each of these series has a radius of convergence of 1.  And each function either

$\bullet$ has a singularity along the edge of the disk of convergence (at 1, $\pm i$, and 1 in the first three examples respectively) or

$\bullet$ has a derivative with a singularity along the edge of the disk of convergence (the last example is this way at 1).

My question is: Suppose a function $f$ is analytic at 0 and its Maclaurin Series has a radius of convergence $r<\infty$.  Does it have to be the case that some derivative (0th, 1st, 2nd, ...) of $f$ blows up somewhere along the edge of the disk of convergence?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

$f(x)=\sum x^n/e^{\sqrt n}$ has radius of convergence 1, and it and all its term-by-term derivatives converge everywhere on the unit circle. Basically, $e^{\sqrt n}$ goes to infinity faster than any polynomial but more slowly than any exponential.

Comment: Thanks!  That's just the kind of example I was looking for.

Comment: Interesting series - if you consider it a Laurent series, it actually also has a _lower_ convergence radius of one, i.e. it only converges for $|x|=1$ if $x\in\mathbb C$ is allowed... It's probably due to the imaginary part [jumping everywhere else](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e938df2ba5e) for $\Im x\neq0$

Comment: @TobiasKienzler: What do you mean by "it only converges for $|x|=1$"? Are you claiming it diverges for $|x|<1$? If so, that is false.

Comment: @Hans It's been a few years since I posted this, so I may misremember, but: If the series is generalized to $$f(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty x^n / e^{\sqrt{|n|}}$$ the inner radius of convergence becomes $r = \limsup_{n\to\infty} |e^{-\sqrt{|n|}}|^{\frac1n} = 1$ as well. My link was wrong then though, since the negative $n$ part was missing, [here's a fix](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%5Bsum%5Bz%5En%2Fexp%5Bsqrt%5Babs%5Bn%5D%5D%5D,%7Bn,-7,7%7D%5D%5D), see also [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pG8Ws.gif).

Comment: @TobiasKienzler: Now this reformulation makes sense. In fact, it makes sense for not taking the absolute value of $n$ as well.

Comment: @Hans True, it works both ways. I wonder if there is an analytical(ish) expression for this function

Comment: @TobiasKienzler: Oops, not so fast. It does not converge without the absolute value for $|x|=1$, and thus it diverges everywhere. It is a good question whether the original version and the Laurent series reformulation analytically continue to a larger domain.

Comment: @TobiasKienzler: I have posted a question derived from this answer and our conversation: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3054504/64809. See if you have anything to add.